# @font-face .ttf files multiple, some working, some failing

Tags: font-face

sorry could be a silly one, but I can't use @font-face with multiples, I have 3 .ttf files saved in the folder 'fonts'

```
@font-face
{
font-family:'sansation';
src: url('fonts/Sansation_light.ttf') format('truetype');
}
p
{
text-align:left;
font-family:'sansation';
font-size:16px;
}
```

The above works fine, but when I do the same thing with the others:

```
@font-face
{
font-family:'ttf_outwrite';
src: url('fonts/outwrite.ttf') format('truetype');
}
a
{
font-size:20px; 
font-family:'ttf_outwrite';
}
```

...it doesn't seem to link at all. Is this possible with multiples .ttf files? 
If you want to try to replicate the issue, the fonts can be downloaded in a few seconds from http://www.fontspace.com/ttf.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: this should be working. Since you claim it is not, there has to be something unrelated to what you have posted here causing the problem... Have you taken a look at: www.google.com/fonts as an alternative?

Comment: in order for me to debug your issue as to why it's not working, I need to see the webpage.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the response, its not on a live system as of yet still testing this locally.

After reading your response, I retried testing out of localhost, into desktop etc, and everytime I try only the sansation font loads.  Please feel free to copy this locally, I'm worried that the font files are corrupt although they look fine. I could email the fonts so you could try it on your local machine if that would help?

Comment: Hi Xarcell, thanks so much about the tip for google fonts by the way, they are great, so handy to integrate. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having the same problem with .ttf files working for some fonts but not others. My solution is a work around in that I converted the font to the woff file type:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "trade";
    src: url(/static/common/fonts/trade-gothic-bold.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/static/common/fonts/trade-gothic-bold.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/static/common/fonts/trade-gothic-bold.woff) format("woff");
}
```

I know this doesn't solve the root problem and was hoping someone had a better answer. My .ttf file is not corrupt because I converted my .woff from it. My thinking is that there has to be something in these non-working .ttf files that make them uninterpretable to the browsers, but not corrupt.